Is this a balanced way to implement the "sparks" spell from Skyrim into D&D?

Sparks
1st level spell
Casting time: 1 action
Range: Self (60-foot line)
Target: Each creature in a 5-foot-wide, 60-foot-long line
Duration: 1 minute concentration
You fire a beam of lightning 60 feet forward in a 5 foot wide line. Each creature in the radius makes a Constitution save, taking 1d8 + spellcasting modifier lightning damage on a failed save and gaining the paralyzed condition until the start of your next turn, or half as much damage with no paralysis on a successful save. At the beginning of each afflicted creature's turn, it remakes the save, ending the paralysis on a successful save. Until the end of the duration, or until you lose concentration, you can take the magic action to cast this spell again without extending the duration or consuming a spell slot.

Basically lightning 1st level sunbeam.
It gives the target 2 chances to avoid the save, and is based on a channeled spell that shoots lightning, dealing damage and sapping the target's energy, so I based it off of sunbeam, since it's like a beam.

Can you provide some more detail on how you came up with the language for this spell? As in, what other spells did you look at? Also, can you provide some details on the elements of Skyrim's spark spells that you're seeking to replicate? (Additional criteria here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/31402)

Sheesh... (bzzzzt) ;)

Skyrim's sparks spell doesn't paralyse (paralysis is an Alteration spell, but whilst the effect can occur with Destruction spells if you take the Deep Freeze perk it only does so with Frost Damage spells and only to enemies with low health) and only affects the first target it hits (rather than all targets in the 60' x 5' area). If you are aiming to port over Skyrim's sparks spell you need to completely rewrite this because this has extremely little in common with Skyrim's sparks

This is too powerful for a level 1 spell, primarily due to the Paralyze condition
The Paralyzed condition is an extremely powerful condition that can end a fight very quickly. It is much more deadly than the Blinded condition from Sunbeam Remember that Paralyzed:

Gives you the Incapacitated Condition which means it breaks concentration, prevents Reactions, Actions and Bonus actions
Automatically makes you fail Strength and Dexterity saving throws
Gives attacks against you advantage
Makes all attackers within 5ft crit when they hit you
Prevents moving

The only two spells available that inflict it are Hold Person, a level 2 spell that's restricted to humanoids and Hold Monster, a level 5 spell.
Multiple targets
On top of that, those spells only affect a single target at their level. This spell, on the other hand, can hit as many targets as you can fit within a cone. Let's be conservative and say you manage to only line it up so it hits two targets. That's still equivalent to a level 3 Hold person or a level 6 Hold Monster.
Two saving throws
As you mention in your comment, you give the target a chance to save against the condition again at the start of their turn. This indeed reduces the risk that a boss monster is stunlocked and can't act at all, but that's still a possible outcome.
On top of that, the damage may already be done by the time the target's turn rolls around, because the free crit, disadvantage on saves and advantage on attacks against it could easily double the party's damage output against an enemy. Imagine if you open a fight with this, the target fails its first save, then your entire party attacks the target with melee attacks that all crit.
You also get to try again and again to stunlock the target
Even if the target saves against the spell, next turn you can just try again until 1 minute is up or your concentration's broken. Even if, say, the target has a 50% chance of making its save, that means it has a 25% chance every single turn for 10 turns to skip its turn entirely, and a 50% chance to take (roughly) double damage from all your allies because of automatic crits. That's not something a first level spell should get.
So how to balance this?
You ask what level this spell should be unchanged, and that's honestly a tricky question to answer because repeatedly applying a condition like this is not something we see much of. I don't think it's an effect that really should exist, either. As said in one of the comments, it's better than an upcast Hold Monster, so that's level 7 at least and it might be higher even.
But honestly, I'd strongly suggest ditching the Paralyzed condition entirely and refocusing the spell on its damage component. If you really do want to apply a debuff of some kind, you could instead reduce the enemy's speed, set it to 0 or introduce some other debuff that doesn't force the enemy to lose an entire turn.

As it currently is, what level spell would be appropriate for this?

Nice answer. I think the way you've worded point 1 ("Gives you the Incapacitated Condition...") implies that the incapacitated condition prevents you from moving. It's the paralyzed condition itself that prevents you from moving, though—incapacitation alone does not. (For example, I believe turn undead now gives targets the incapacitated condition and requires them to move away each turn).

Good catch,  @nben. Thank you, corrected

@Tasi: It's substantially stronger than an upcast 6th level Hold Monster (because you can keep trying to reapply the effect, even if they save), so that's a minimum of 7th level. I'd suggest you redesign it more fundamentally, rather than just changing its level.

The damage doesn't fit with existing spells
Not directly balance-related, but a note: The only spells in 5E-2024 that add the spellcaster's ability modifier to the damage are:

Spells that make weapons (and add to the weapon's attack damage) and
Spells that summon creatures to fight for you (and add to their attack damage)

For direct damage spells, no such spells exist, it's only class features that add it on (e.g. Agonizing Blast to add it to a single cantrip for Warlocks, or the level 10 Evoker ability to add it to a single damage roll of a spell). So having your spell do 1d8 + spellcasting modifier damage, balanced or not, is out of step with other spells.
As noted in the other answer, this is far too powerful for a low level spell
I agree with the other answer that the spell is fundamentally way too powerful for a low-level spell. The only way I can see this approaching the power level of a low-level spell would be some combination of:

A less debilitating condition. Stunned would remove the autocrits and zeroed movement that Paralyzed imposes, but even denying Str/Dex saves and granting advantage on attacks is too much for a low-level spell that's also reducing the target's action economy (e.g. First-level Faerie Fire only grants advantage, but the only thing it stacks on that is suppressing invisibility; it doesn't stack damage, denial of Str/Dex saves, zero movement, and deny all actions as well). Incapacitated would be the most I could see allowing; it still denies actions and breaks concentration, but it doesn't grant opponents advantage on attack rolls, nor grant autocrits, nor deny movement.
A shorter duration; the spell goes off once, not every round for a minute, and the Incapacitated condition only lasts until the end of the creature's next turn (or perhaps to the start of your own next turn, so Reactions are suppressed for a full round, even if the creature acts immediately after you in the initiative order), not a whole minute
A reduced area of effect; halving the line length to 30ft wouldn't do a lot to reduce the number of creatures hit (it's unusual to have enemies spread out far enough, in a row, for this to matter), but it would at least impose a cost on the caster, similar to Burning Hands: They have to get close enough to risk reprisal from melee opponents.
Lower, and standard, damage: Given how incredibly useful even a small area Incapacitated effect is, this spell shouldn't be about damage. Have it do 1d8, and remove the highly non-standard addition of spellcasting ability modifier to damage.

If you do all this, you don't even need to allow the save at the start of their next turn. The spell can be reasonably assumed to be used primarily to deny enemy actions; you'd spend your action to, typically, deny a single turn's worth of actions to 1-2 enemies (assuming you can regularly manage to target 2-3 enemies, and 1-2 of them fail the save), and do token damage. You might allow upcasting to do extra dice of damage, and enough upcasting to impose Stunned or Paralyzed rather than Incapacitated, where it would be inferior to Hold Person/Monster in duration, but superior in damage and number of targets.
Even with all this though, I'd generally consider it a level 2 minimum spell. Area effects spells that ruin the enemy's action economy, even briefly, are a big deal. If you granted this at level 1, it would be far too attractive, being much better than any other control spell options available at that level.
After these changes, I'd view this as roughly analogous to Silvery Barbs from 5E-2014: It's doing the work of multiple other spells, but doing it less effectively than the spells it's borrowing from. Silvery Barbs is a mixture of Shield's defensive benefits (but a less reliable) and Faerie Fire's granting advantage (but single use for single person, not a "for a whole minute for everyone"). This spell combines aspects of Hold Person and Burning Hands; a close-ish range multi-target damaging spell that is a little harder to use than Burning Hands and does less damage, combined with a less debilitating and shorter duration Hold Person (but without the creature type restrictions, and the ability to target multiple targets, which Hold Person can't do without upcasting). It's still a very good spell, and might be more desirable than Hold Person for certain builds (just like Silvery Barbs was unusually synergistic with Arcane Trickster Rogues, this multi-target short-acting debuff without Concentration might be better than a longer duration spell that requires Concentration to lock down a single enemy), but I don't think it would be wildly out of bounds, power-wise, for second level spells.

+1 for noting the AOE size and discussing alternate conditions.

Hold Monster (5th) is the version that has no creature-type restrictions.  And that's single target, and you don't get to keep targeting other creatures without spending more spell slots.  AoE incapacitate or stronger that doesn't break on damage is very strong.  (I think you're already proposing reducing it to 1 try per spell slot and to 1 round incapacitate for it to be lvl2?) The only standard spell I saw with that is Psychic Scream (9th), although that's a much wider area than just a Line.  I posted an answer with a list of some damage + control spells to compare against for power level.

Yes, the proposal was to limit it to one Line effect on the round it was cast and no more, and one round of effect, and no more. For a small line as proposed, the multitarget aspect is likely to be just 2-3 targets, so it's not completely overboard. I suppose making even that one round tied to concentration (so the allies who have actions can free their buddies) could make sense to further depower it.

The great other answers focus on a D&D perspective. I'll add mine based on knowledge of Skyrim:
Take the paralysis out of the spell and make it a feat
In Skyrim, Sparks doesn't have a status effect built in. All it does is damage and reduce the enemy's magicka (their mana bar). There is no stun effect to it in vanilla Skyrim. There is a skill in Destruction that staggers when dual casting, but it is not limited to Sparks, it affects all damaging spells.
For that reason, it seems to me that it would not only reduce the spell's power level, but also make more thematic sense, to move the status part to a feat that would work on all lightning damage spells. This would follow more closely the way that Skyrim enhances magic : simple spells, with additional effects from leveling up a skill.
About the magicka reduction
If you really want to imitate the magic drain effect from Sparks in the base spell, you could write a less powerful condition that targets spell casting specifically, for instance :
Mute - A muted creature cannot cast spells that require verbal components.
Of course, if you choose to add this kind of effect, the damage of the spell should be reduced.

Note: I'd be very leery of putting an effect like that into a feat. Even written very narrowly (say, only affects a single known spell, mandatory upcast to gain effect, etc.), a feat that upgrades spells to add things that reduce enemy action economy is a massive boost to power that will interact unpredictably with other spells (e.g. if it affects all targets, the bigger the AoE, the better, especially if it has friend-or-foe recognition). Feats rarely improve your abilities that much; they do more damage, or enable more attacks, they don't give you anything this powerful.


it's an electric channeled spell that shoots a beam of lightning and drains the energy of those hit. I took inspiration from sunbeam to write the spell description

As other have said, it's unclear how you came up with an AoE Paralyze after looking at that, especially for a 1st level spell.  Especially one that can last multiple rounds if they keep failing saves; Sunbeam's Blinded condition only lasts "until the start of your next turn".
Even without any damage, this would be a powerful debuff spell, an AoE Hold Monster (5th).  (That also gives a save every round to un-paralyze.)  And Hold Monster is just single-target, not every round for a minute from the same spell slot.
Your spell does damage and is much stronger than Tasha's Hideous Laughter (1st) which gives a weaker condition and can break early on damage, as well as giving a save every round.
Other spells you could look at that have damage plus status / control effects other than blinded or prone:

Shocking Grasp (cantrip): single-target 1d8 lightning damage.  No Opportunity Attacks until the start of its next turn.  (dnd-2014: no reactions of any kind).
Ray of Sickness (1st): single-target 2d8 poison on hit, Poisoned condition  until the end of your next turn.
various Smite spells that do damage and save vs. effect, in dnd-2024 they're bonus actions you cast after hitting.  e.g. Frightened from Wrathful Smite, Stunned for a round from Staggering Smite (4th).
Mind Whip (2nd): single-target 3d6 psychic, save for half.  On fail, no reactions until end of its next turn, and on that turn only one of action / bonus / movement.
Psychic Lance (4th): single-target 7d6 psychic save for half, incapacitate on fail until the start of your next turn.
Phantasmal Killer (4th): single target save vs. 4d10 psychic and disadvantage on checks and attacks, repeat the save every turn.
Sickening Radiance (4th): AoE 4d10 radiant, save for half, temporary level of exhaustion on fail.
Psychic Scream (9th): AoE 14d6 psychic, save for half.  On fail, stunned until it succeeds an Int save (at the end of each of its turns).

And various that include Restrained, which I've separated out since they have a different kind of flavour and Restrained doesn't prevent enemy spellcasters from casting.  Neither of these lists are exhaustive.

Earthen Grasp (2nd): single-target, save vs. 2d6 bludgeoning and restrained for the spell's duration.  (Target can spend an action to attempt a strength check (not save) to get out if they want.)
Conjure Elemental (5th): the elemental forces a nearby creature to save vs. 8d8 damage plus Restrained, repeating the save on later turns.



[...] in a 5 foot wide line. Each creature in the radius [...]

Radius is not the normal phrasing for talking about AoEs with a shape other than sphere.  Sunbeam 2024 for example says "You launch a sunbeam in a 5-foot-wide, 60-foot-long Line. Each creature in the Line makes a Constitution saving throw".
A "Line" is one of the volumes that the rules define how to work with, so "in the Line" tells readers they should go check the AoE rules for how Lines work.  (Interesting that dnd-2024 capitalizes Line, like a proper noun, I guess to highlight that its a technical game term with that specific meaning in this context.)

you can take the magic action to cast this spell again without extending the duration or consuming a spell slot.

Why talk about casting it again?  Sunbeam's wording seems simpler and fine: "Until the spell ends, you can take a Magic action to create a new Line of radiance."
There are at least three differences; IDK if any of these are why you chose that wording:

Counterspell is usable against every attempt.  Unclear if being counterspelled would end your concentration or not since.  Casting doesn't extend the duration of the original casting, so you might read it as later castings not requiring concentration at all, just creating the line effect.  Or since it's a concentration spell, the new casting replaces the old one.  In fact, some argue there's a moment during the cast time when the previous duration has ended but the new hasn't started, as in Countering a concentration spell while concentrating on darkness  So disrupting the new cast means the old one is still lost but the new one doesn't start.

(depending on interpretation) For similar reasons, the original cast ends, un-paralyzing any creatures that were still affected by it?  So you can only have one line worth of creatures paralyzed at once?  I don't think that was your design intent, but "without extending the duration" seems ambiguous.  So if you really want this design, decide what you want for each of these bullet points and write wording that makes it clear what you mean.

You're actually casting a spell as your action, and it's a 1st level spell.  So the only other spells you can cast on your turn are cantrips.  Unlike with other concentration spells that let you use an action or bonus on later turns.  (This doesn't come close to mitigating how over-powered this is, even if it was 5th level.)

You're casting a spell so you could Quicken Spell on it.  Unlike if it was just another way to use your action.



(I didn't notice that it gives the target 2 chances to save before losing their turn to the paralyzed condition.  It's still strong offensively for melee auto-crits, and still very strong against multiple targets especially with weaker Wis saves, especially for a higher-level caster with a save DC like 16 to 18, not like a tier 1 caster with save DC 13 to 14.)
